# Java Nested Ifs - Could it be solved by coding best practices?

Tags: java, design-patterns, if-statement, refactoring

I have some code I wrote, Just wondering if there is a neater way of doing it in case I have to do extra conditions? I would like to not have to use nested ifs.

Is there a way to make it more Object Oriented?

```
  if(!usernameExists)
  {
      if(!username.matches("^[\\pL\\pN]+$") || 
          username.length() < 7 || 
          username.length() > 25)
      {
          usernameValid=false;
          Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.red);
          Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText(
             "<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between 6 and 26</html>");
      }
      else
      {
          Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.white);
          Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("");
      }
  }
  else
  {
      usernameValid=false;
      Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.red);
      Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText(
          "This username already exists!");
  }
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com would be better for this type of question.

Comment: If the username doesn't exist, then you check if the username matches a pattern? That doesn't look right.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot looks ok to me, user name must not be taken already and fulfill some complexity criteria.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot The username will only exist if it is valid. What he is doing is fine, no point in doing a regex check and all if the name already exists anyway.

Comment: belongs on code-review site

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey yet you answered anyway..

Comment: @turbo: Well, sure; once (if) it's migrated the answers still apply.

Comment: I want to contribute to this question. I think this question has a lot about programming. I think this could be resolved with a design pattern. Could it be reopened?

Comment: I think with the question's refactoring this could be re-open.

Comment: Please, reopen this question.

Answer (score 3):

I make no assumptions about the correctness of your logic as presented, but for what is shown to me, I would recommend that you refactor and extract the first boolean into a separate method.

```
if(!usernameExists) {
    usernameValid = validateUsernameAndSetBackground(username);
} else {
    // rest of code
}


public boolean validateUsernameAndSetBackground(String username) {
    boolean result = true;
    if(!username.matches("^[\\pL\\pN]+$") || username.length() < 7 || username.length() > 25) {
        result = false;
        Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.red);
        Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between 6 and 26</html>");
    } else {
        Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.white);
        Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("");
    }
    return result;
}
```

There's other opportunities for refactoring, too - namely the setting of background colors and fields.  But this tackles the immediate issue of there being a lot of conditional clauses deeply nested.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is the following.
This gets rid of some magic numbers and spreads responsibility a bit.

```
public static final String USERNAME_KEY = "^[\\pL\\pN]+$";
public static final int USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 7;
public static final int USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH = 25;

void foo() {
    if(!usernameExists) {
        usernameValid = validateUsernameAndSetBackground(username);
    } else {
        usernameValid = false;
        adjustFormSettings(Color.red, "This username already exists!");
    }
}


private boolean validateUsernameAndSetBackground(String username) {
    if(usernameIsValid(username)) {
        adjustFormSettings(Color.white, "");
        return true;
    } else {
        adjustFormSettings(Color.red, getInvalidUsernameErrorMsg());
        return false;
    }
}

private void adjustFormSettings(Color color, String msg) {
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.red);
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText(getErrorMsg());
}

private boolean usernameIsValid(String username) {
    return username.matches(USERNAME_KEY) 
     && username.length() >= USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH 
     && username.length() <= USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH;
}

private String getInvalidUsernameErrorMsg() {
    return "<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between "
     + USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH + " and " + USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH + ".</html>";
}
```

Comment: Also makes it easier to test!

Answer (score 0):

I would reformat your example as follows. (Note I use an uncommon indent for the closing '}'):

```
if(usernameExists) {
    usernameValid=false;
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.red);
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("This username already exists!");
    }
else if(!username.matches("^[\\pL\\pN]+$") || username.length() < 7 || username.length() > 25) {
    usernameValid=false;
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.red);
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between 6 and 26</html>");
    }
else if(/* other validation conditions here...*/) {
    }
else {
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.white);
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: use defaults.

```
usernameValid=false;
Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.red);
Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("This username already exists!");

if (!usernameExists) {
    usernameValid=true;
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.white);
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("");

    if(!username.matches("^[\\pL\\pN]+$") || username.length() < 7 || username.length() > 25) {
        usernameValid=false;
        Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(Color.red);
        Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between 6 and 26</html>");
    }
}
```

Second step: eliminate redundant information

```
Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("This username already exists!");

if (!usernameExists) {
    Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("");

    if(!username.matches("^[\\pL\\pN]+$") || username.length() < 7 || username.length() > 25) {
        Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText("<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between 6 and 26</html>");
    }
}

boolean usernameValid = Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.getToolTipText().length() > 0);
Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(usernameValid ? Color.white : Color.red);
```

Third step: replace technical information

```
String error = "This username already exists!";

if (!usernameExists) {
    error = "";

    if(!username.matches("^[\\pL\\pN]+$") || username.length() < 7 || username.length() > 25) {
        error = "<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between 6 and 26</html>";
    }
}

Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText(error);
boolean usernameValid = error.length() > 0;
Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(usernameValid ? Color.white : Color.red);
```

Fourth step: reduce nests

```
String error = usernameExists ? "This username already exists!" : "";

if("".equals(error) && (!username.matches("^[\\pL\\pN]+$") || username.length() < 7 || username.length() > 25)) {
    error = "<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between 6 and 26</html>";
}

Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText(error);
boolean usernameValid = "".equals(error) == false;
Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(usernameValid ? Color.white : Color.red);
```

Fifth step: make more meaningful methods

```
boolean isUsernameValid(String username) {
    return !username.matches("^[\\pL\\pN]+$") || username.length() < 7 || username.length() > 25);
}

boolean noErrors(error) {
    return "".equals(error);
}

String error = usernameExists ? "This username already exists!" : "";

if(noErrors(error) && isUsernameValid(username) == false) {
    error = "<html>Only letters & numbers allowed!<br> Length must be between 6 and 26</html>";
}

boolean usernameValid = noErrors(error);
Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setToolTipText(error);
Forms.Main.instructorForm.usernameField.setBackground(usernameValid ? Color.white : Color.red);
```